# Combining 2 string into one array?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I need to make different operation on 2 fields that can have 3 types : null, string, array.

My goal is to combined the two fields in every situation. But for the situation where both `"fieldIDA"` and `"fieldIDB"` are of string type I can't manage to find a way of combining those 2 string into on array.

Below a sample of the `$switch` I am using currently for this task.

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
        {$project : {
         "item":1,
         "objetJointure":{$switch:{
             branches: [
                 {case: {$and : [ {  {$eq: [ { $type: "fieldIDA" },"string"] } },{ {$eq: [ { $type: "fieldIDB" },"string"] } } ] },then :},
                 {case: {$and : [ {  {$eq: [ { $type: "fieldIDA" },"string"] } },{ {$eq: [ { $type: "fieldIDB" },"array"] } } ] },then : { $push: { "fieldIDB": "fieldIDA" } }},
                 {case: {$and : [ {  {$eq: [ { $type: "fieldIDA" },"array"] } },{ {$eq: [ { $type: "fieldIDB" },"string"] } } ] },then : { $push: { "fieldIDA": "fieldIDB" }},
             ]
         }}
        }},
         ])
```

(I can't show a sample of data)

there is a dummy sample :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df8b596400289966e77e268"),
    "fieldIDA" : "1496461ahu-45196tfvj",
    "fieldIDB" : "4446rarr21-vau15ar6a"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df9ee6014585733585abde6"),
    "fieldIDA" : "78a24da5ea-a0a84tf5t",
    "fieldIDB" : [ 
        "17a7a61a78-4649atfvj", 
        "149648a6a1-777777fvj", 
        "4846131prv-45aeda8vj"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df9ee6014585733585abde9"),
    "fieldIDA" : null,
    "fieldIDB" : "7a25rayfg7-t69468a8v"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df9ffe714585733585ac5b8"),
    "fieldIDA" : [ 
        "4946465434-vuhfyfuog", 
        "198fdyufu5-4654d43dc", 
        "aeadad596a-aead82a2a"
    ],
    "fieldIDB" : [ 
        "17a7a61a78-4649atfvj", 
        "149648a6a1-777777fvj", 
        "4846131prv-45aeda8vj"
    ]
}
```

In the case of the first document I need to join put the 2 string of `"fieldIDA"` and `"fieldIDB"` into one array composed of those 2 string.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        "fieldIDA": {
            "$cond": [
                { $isArray: "$fieldIDA" },
                "$fieldIDA",
                ['$fieldIDA']
            ]
        }
        , "fieldIDB": {
            "$cond": [
                { $isArray: "$fieldIDB" },
                "$fieldIDB",
                ['$fieldIDB']
            ]
        }
    }
}, { $addFields: { objectJointure: { $setUnion: ["$fieldIDA", "$fieldIDB"] } } }])
```

This aggregation above is working for my problem

Comment: can you please post a dummy sample data and also the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this for the given data :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        "fieldIDA": {
            "$cond": [
                { $isArray: "$fieldIDA" },
                "$fieldIDA",
                ['$fieldIDA']
            ]
        }
        , "fieldIDB": {
            "$cond": [
                { $isArray: "$fieldIDB" },
                "$fieldIDB",
                ['$fieldIDB']
            ]
        }
    }
}, { $addFields: { objectJointure: { $setUnion: ["$fieldIDA", "$fieldIDB"] } } }])
```

You could use `$project` instead of `$addFields` in the last stage if you don't want a new field along with existing, same way you can use `$addFields` as your first stage if you want this operation to be done along with existing fields.

**Ref :** [mongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

Comment: Thx for the answer ! Your response work but I have other condition on the value that make this redaction a bit heavy.

Comment: @BrunoSENELLART  : what do you mean by another condition on value? Basically you don’t have iterate between n num of switch statements with this - which is not needed plus we don’t have to add a new switch statement for a new data type(null or number or anyother) on either of the fields..!!

Comment: Well those  field can either way be null, string or array. I need to check all the possible combination to return the good format. 
So there is 9 possibilities that's why I went for a `$switch`, because I could treat all thoses différents cases in one block.

Comment: @BrunoSENELLART : exactly is there a case where this is failing?

Comment: No that's why I say it worked. It does indeed take all the case where both are string and make an array of them. 
But I need to treat the rest of the case, in my situation I want all the case to be reformated and put in one big array list.
So I iterate on every case and reformate them accordingly.

Comment: @BrunoSENELLART : ok a bit confused when you say : ‘I need to treat the ......one big array list’, can you give me a sample of one another case from ‘rest of the case’ just wanted to know if any use case is missed as my assumption is this is for n*n..

Comment: I will edit the question, but your answer still answer the question of the post which is join 2 string into one array list composed of those 2 string.

Comment: @BrunoSENELLART : please do edit but not getting what exactly the missing usecases are but in general this query should cover not only (string, string) but also (string, null) (null, string) (null, array) (array,null) (array, string)(string, array) (array, array) or even (null, null) to merge into an array with values from both fields(it will eliminate use of switch cases). Use $push instead of $setUnion if you can accept duplicates in the array..

Comment: I am a bit confused I tested on my dummy sample and it worked just finned in did. 
But on my actual data it return null when both field are array

Comment: ok after some testing and adjustement to my case your solution seems to work. Thx again and sorry for my earlier mistake.

Answer (score 1):

> In the case of the first document I need to join put the 2 string of
>   "fieldIDA" and "fieldIDB" into one array composed of those 2 string.

The following `case` statement within `switch` does that:

```
{ 
  case: { $and: [ 
                 { $eq: [ { $type: "$fieldIDA" }, "string" ] }, 
                 { $eq: [ { $type: "$fieldIDB" }, "string" ] } 
          ] 
        },
  then : [ "$fieldIDA", "$fieldIDB" ] 
}
```

The complete query (altered to work):

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { $project : {
        "objetJointure": {
            $switch: {
                branches: [
                    { case: { $and: [ { $eq: [ { $type: "$fieldIDA" }, "string" ] }, { $eq: [ { $type: "$fieldIDB" }, "string" ] } ] },
                        then : [ "$fieldIDA", "$fieldIDB" ] 
                    },
                    { case: { $and: [ { $eq: [ { $type: "$fieldIDA" }, "string" ] }, { $eq: [ { $type: "$fieldIDB" }, "array" ] } ] },
                        then : { $concatArrays: [ [ "$fieldIDA" ], "$fieldIDB" ] }
                    },
                    { case: { $and: [ { $eq: [ { $type: "$fieldIDA" }, "array" ] }, { $eq: [ { $type: "$fieldIDB" }, "string" ] } ] },
                        then : { $concatArrays: [ "$fieldIDA", [ "$fieldIDB" ] ] }
                    }
                 ],
                 default: "DEFAULT"
            }
        }
  } },
] )
```